# BelongsToMany eager loading returns multiple objects for each association

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have two models: User and EconomicActivity. They are associated through UserEconomicActivity (it's a BelongsToMany relation). In User model, I have defined the association like this:

```js
this.belongsToMany(models.EconomicActivity, {
  through: 'UserEconomicActivity',
  as: 'economicActivities',
  otherKey: {
    name: 'economicActivityId',
    allowNull: false
  },
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'userId',
    allowNull: false
  }
})
```

I'm trying to query User where it is associated with one or more EconomicActivity, like this:

```js
const users = await User.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: EconomicActivity,
      as: 'economicActivities',
      where: {
        id: filters.economicActivities // This is an array with IDs I want to filter
      }
    }
  ],
  raw: true,
  nest: true
})
```

Let's say that one specific User is associated to 2 EconomicActivity. When I run this query, it returns the same user two times, one for each association. I want to return the same user just one time with an array of associated economicActivities inside it (like user.economicActivities). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, I needed to use raw and nest because I'm passing the data to Handlebars, and Handlebars can only output plain JavaScript objects, otherwise it gives me the error `Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "name" because it is not an "own property" of its parent` and will not output the data.

But, I found a way to get a plain JavaScript object and also keeping all the associations inside an array:

```js
await this.model.findAll(query).map(item => item.get({ plain: true }))
```

The model's `get` method does exactly what I want. Because I'm using `findAll`, I use ES6 map method to call `get` from every model returned from the query.

Answer (score 1):

By setting `raw` to true, you're explicitly asking for this result format.
I also don't see the use of `nest` here.

I suggest you remove both parameters.

See [the Sequelize API Reference](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-query) for more info.

Comment: I need it to return as a plain JavaScript object because I will output this in a Handlebars template file. If I don't use raw, Handlebars will give me a warning (Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "name" because it is not an "own property" of its parent) and will not output the properties. I'm also using nest so that the proper objects are created (I have more includes, I'm just omitting it here).